# How can I control the way gcc/g++ automatically includes headers?

Tags: gcc, include, g++, header, compilation

I've run into trouble in the past when I've tried porting some C++ code written on Mac OS X to a Linux system, or trying to compile code written against an older version of gcc/g++ with a newer one:

It seems that some (older?) versions of gcc/g++ would automatically include some header files for you.

For example, code that uses `printf` should require `#include <stdio.h>`. And code that uses `memcpy` should require `#include <string.h>`. But depending on the version of gcc I'm using, it will occasionally include these for me.

It wreaks havoc when I forget to include something and then *never get errors* until I go to compile the code on another system. At that point it's a game of running all over the project and fixing the includes.

Has anyone else run into this? Is there a way to force gcc to autoinclude or to not autoinclude? Or, is there a way to know *what* it's autoincluding?

Comment: May be if gcc does it automatically it would become too subtle for it to understand same methods names in different libraries. But if there is some automatic solution I would like to know.

Comment: Are you sure it's not other headers pulling those one's in, and on the other platforms not doing so?

Comment: gcc doesn't "auto include" - you're probably just getting indirect includes via headers that you have explicitly #included, as Preet suggest above. Bottom line: you need to fix your code.

Comment: @Preet, thanks for that suggestion. I bet that's what is happening. If you want to make that suggestion as an answer I'll check it off.

Comment: @PaulR: No, gcc does "auto include" stuff. On several computers I have access to, `int main(){printf("Hello world\n");}` compiles fine without any includes. I've tested both using gcc 4.6.3, gcc 4.9.2 and clang 3.5.0, both on linux. But on a mac it doesn't work. So this is clearly system dependent, and I wish it were documented somewhere. Too bad the poster here ended up getting the wrong answers.

Comment: It'd be nice if there were some dependency graph laying out the major header files and what they include on each type of system.

Comment: @amaurea: when you say "compiles fine" I suspect that you're (a) compiling C code rather than C++ and (b) relying on C89 behaviour, where you can get away with not declaring functions prior to use. However this is very unreliable, particularly on 64 bit systems, since pointer params will be assumed to be int.

Comment: @PaulR: You're right, this was C code. It didn't occur to me that this could be due to functions being accepted without needing any declaration. I had assumed that they were somehow being included by default. I wasn't advocating this as something to rely on, though. I had encountered it in the same situation as the original poster, where something would compile fine on one compiler, while another would balk about undefined functions. In this case the way around this is to just specify a newer standard than C89, I guess.

Comment: @amaurea: yes, in general always compile with at least `-Wall`, and `-pedantic` too, if possible - that way you never rely on things like implicit int, undeclared prototypes, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you sure it's not other headers pulling those one's in, and on the other platforms not doing so?

Answer (score 5):

-include file
Process file as if #include "file" appeared as the first line of the primary source file. However, the first directory searched for file is the preprocessor's working directory instead of the directory containing the main source file. If not found there, it is searched for in the remainder of the #include "..." search chain as normal.
If multiple -include options are given, the files are included in the order they appear on the command line.

http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Preprocessor-Options.html

Answer (score 0):

When compiling on different systems, you might meet different problems and not only includes.
I would suggest investing in a continuous build system that will compile on all OS you need after each update of the code, so you are rapidly aware of any portability issue.

You can also put all common system header files inside a specific header file you will write and systematically include it in all your files.

Comment: This is a good suggestion, but in one case, it was a third party library (an old version of OpenSceneGraph) and some old code that broke when upgrading to a newer version of gcc. Auto-compiling for multiple OSes wouldn't have helped here, and I suspect that maybe the problem was just that #includes inside the system include files were reorganized between gcc releases :/